# Active admin dashboard redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

When an admin logs in, it automatically redirects to the main home page (i.e. not the admin dashboard). It is happening because i have already specified a dashboard_path in my application controller therefore it always redirects to that path. can anyone tell me how can i chnage path for active_admin.

**Application_controller.rb**

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  admin_dasboard_path || session[:application_url] || dashboard_path
end
```

It is not working for admin.

Comment: Can you describe what is not working? Is there an error in the log or console, or does it not act as you would like (what does it do?). Please edit your post with a little more information so we can help. Does the `after_sign_in_path_for` method get called at all?

Answer (score 0):

Load an Active Admin initializer file and define **`config.load_paths`** to set the new url / endpoint of active admin. More details [here](https://activeadmin.info/1-general-configuration.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think I've had the same issue. I was trying to configure Devise methods. Instead it should've been Action Controller filter methods.

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page 'Dashboard' do
    controller do
        before_action do |_|
            redirect_to home_admin_path
        end
    end
end
```